# EntityManager persist multiple relationship

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have spring boot rest api, I have persisted 1 table successfully, but when I tried to persist object which has 2 another relations and I got error:

> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1364, SQLState:
>   HY000
>       o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

here is my entity and entity manger persistance:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="booking")
public class Booking {  
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id; 
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="booking",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<CategoriesBooking> bookingInfos = new ArrayList<>();

@Entity
@Table(name="category_booking")
public class CategoriesBooking {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name")  
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="booking_id")
    private Booking booking;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="categoriesBooking",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  
    private List<OptionsBooking> options = new ArrayList<>();



@Entity
@Table(name="options_booking")
public class OptionsBooking {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "catebooking_id")    
    private CategoriesBooking categoriesBooking;

@Transactional
@Repository
public class Services{
    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public Services() {     
    }   
    public boolean add(Booking booking){
        try {
            entityManager.persist(booking);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();          
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

data:

```
{description: 'test for persist',
bookingInfos:[{
name:'test1',
options:[{
  name: 'test1-test1'
 }]
}]
}
```

I update for use MySQL

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? How are the ID columns defined?

Comment: Please do not change the question so that it becomes a different one, especially when it has answers. This would make the answers nonsensical. I rolled back your changes. Please create a new question instead and if one of the answers helped with this question upvote it and if it fixed the problem accept it as correct, so others have a better chance to find helpful and correct answers to the problem.

Comment: can you try changing "private int id;" to "private Integer id;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GenerationType.AUTO` chooses an ID generation strategy suitable for your database. What it actually picks depends on the database you are using. But judging from the error message it assumes the `id` column to be some kind of `IDENTITY` field which creates a unique value upon insertion.

And it seems your schema doesn't declare the `id` column in this way.

The obvious fix is to change that.

Comment: I have fixed by add 'implements Serializable' for Entity but I still got error, and I have update error on the post.

Comment: I think the issue which I set id for auto increases, so the children can not persist without the id of parent.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes changes made to the model or to the ORM may not reflect accurately on the database even after an execution of `SchemaUpdate`.

If the error actually seems to lack a sensible explanation, try recreating the database (or at least creating a new one) and scaffolding it with `SchemaExport`.

Comment: I have fixed by add 'implements Serializable' for Entity but I still got error, and I have update error on the post.